# Accessing Child records field in VF page using Parent object as Standard Controller

Tags: visualforce

I have Parent child relationship With Account and Child Account Object in Salesforce. Now, One Account can have multiple child account associated with it.
I was trying to show 'Child Account' object's address field in the VF that is using 'Account' object as standard controller.
Any idea if that is feasible?

My code snippet looks like below -

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account">
.
.
.
 var Parent_address = "{!Account.Street},{!Account.City},{!Account.PostalCode},{!Account.Country}";
 var Child_address = "{!Child_Account__c.Street},{!Child_Account__c.City},{!Child_Account__c.PostalCode},{!Child_Account__c.Country}";
```

Comment: Any reason why exactly Account is being used as standard controller?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display all child records addresses in a table,with one row per record, you can use an apex repeat tag, as demonstrated in the documentation for the tag.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm

Answer (score 0):

Make Child_Account__c as a standard controller

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Child_Account__c">
      var accountName = "{!Child_Account__c.Account__r.Name}";
      var childAccountName = "{!Child_Account__c.Name}"; 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you are feasible with making the standard Controller as Child Object , Then Use the following Code:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Child_of_Account__c">
   <apex:outputfield value="{!Child_of_Account__c.Account__r.Name}"/>   
<apex:outputfield value="{!Child_of_Account__c.Name}"/>   

</apex:page>
```

And If you are not feasible with it and you want to standard controller as Parent object then you need to create a class and make a Inner Query through which you can retrieve the data on the visualforce page.

For an example : `SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Job_Applications__r) FROM Position__c`

Thanks,
Vipul